# How to capture screen shots of various operating systems in java?

Tags: java, awtrobot

I am working on Java project. I need to capture screens shots of different operating systems.

```
String outFileName = "c:\\Windows\\Temp\\screen.jpg";
 try{
    long time = Long.parseLong(secs) * 1000L;
    System.out.println("Waiting " + (time / 1000L) + " second(s)...");
    //Thread.sleep(time);
    Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension screenSize = toolkit.getScreenSize();
    Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(screenSize);
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File(outFileName));
  }catch(Exception screen){}
```

Using the above code it is capturing the screen shots from Windows XP but it is not capturing in other operating systems. Is there any other method I need to keep to make it work in all operating systems?

Comment: Please explain _"not capturing in other operating systems"_. Exception? Empty output file? Something else?  You're ignoring all exceptions, which means you may not be seeing the cause of failure.  At least print the stack trace in the `catch` block.

Comment: First of all: **never** ignore exceptions with an empty catch block like this. *At least* use `e.printStackTrace()` (oh, and don't call your exception variable `screen`, that's just confusing).

Comment: @JoachimSauer or just throw up[wards]. The runtime environment will display the error for you.

Comment: Also: that path is *probably* not valid on most non-Windows OS.

Answer (score 2):

This is a **very** watered down version of some of the code we use...

```
try {

    Robot robot = new Robot();

    GraphicsDevice[] screenDevices = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices();
    Area area = new Area();
    for (GraphicsDevice gd : screenDevices) {
        area.add(new Area(gd.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds()));
    }

    Rectangle bounds = area.getBounds();
    System.out.println(bounds);
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(bounds.width, bounds.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
    for (GraphicsDevice gd : screenDevices) {
        Rectangle screenBounds = gd.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
        BufferedImage screenCapture = robot.createScreenCapture(screenBounds);
        g2d.drawImage(screenCapture, screenBounds.x, screenBounds.y, null);
    }

    g2d.dispose();
    ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("path/to/ScreenShot.png"));

} catch (Exception exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

This works on Windows 7 and XP.  I'll test my Mac when I get home

**UPDATED**

I've being able to verify Mac OS 10.7.5 using JDK 7 and JDK 6